# Accepted new job and they've asked for current employer reference

Tags: resignation, ethics

I started a job last month and I am not enjoying it. My dream job got back to me last week and gave me a job offer that starts in September.I accepted the offer.

Now the new job wants a reference from my current employer.But, I can't leave my current job till August to keep up with bills etc. And they have no idea I want to leave so soon.

What do I do?
FYI- I am based in the Uk

- on probation so-one weeks notice period

Comment: talk to the people at the new job?  "hey they don't know I'm leaving yet."

Comment: Why are they asking for a reference _AFTER_ hiring you? That should have been part of their decision process before making the offer. Which, of course, would yield the same issue of "do I tell my current employer", which in this case I'd answer "yes" to since they'd rather know a mistake was known immediately so they can contact their next-best-choice candidate before they are grabbed by someone else.

Answer (score 17):

In this scenario, I would most likely talk to the new job hiring manager and tell them straight up - you started a new job about a month ago, it isn't what you expected and you only accepted the offer as you hadn't received an offer from them.

Then let them take the conversation from there - most likely they will want a reference from your previous employer, which should be sufficient.

The hiring manager should know that any reference for an employee that has only been in a new position for a Month isn't going to provide much in the way of value.

Comment: I would add to this: If you explain your situation to your new employer they should understand. As well as the above, tell them that you've not yet handed in your notice, that you're concerned that when you do they might want you to leave as soon as possible, that you need the income from this job, so you want to tell them as late as possible. And when you've given in your notice you'll tell your new employer and they can get a reference. And they might prefer to get a reference from your last employer, which will be more meaningful as you were there longer.

Answer (score 6):

> What do I do?

Just say that you are sorry, but you can't do that. Explain further only if you must.

Try to find references from your prior job, since presumably it would only be a few months ago. And if you have a trusted friend in your company, ask if they would do it.